# created input form by json doesn't show in $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, post

I use `json` for retrieving data from database. When I click on an option it retrieves some input form. But when I print $_POST it doesn't show those inputs.

`print_r($_POST);` // print all except input fields which retrieved from json

My php code:

```
foreach($html->result() as $row){
   $html_input .= '<input name="' . $row->Feature_Eng_Name . '" type="text" style="color:#888" placeholder="'. $row->Feature_Name . '">';
   $html_input .= "<br>";                
}
$result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $html_input);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#maintype").click(function(){
            var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" ;
            var isOption = $("option:selected").val();
            var cat_id = isOption;  
            if(isOption == ""){
                $("#feature_ajax").html("");                    
            }
            else{
                $.post(base_url + 'administrator/submit_product/ajax_get_feature_by_cat', {cat_id}, function(data){
                    if(data.status == 'ok'){                            
                        //alert("yes");
                        $('#feature_ajax').html(data.content);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#feature_ajax').html("");
                    }
                }, "json");
            }                
        });
    });
```

Comment: your question is confusing. Can you clarify? Perhaps show the code in your controller and in your JS so we can see the ajax.

Comment: @CodeGodie Please check Script part and completed php part. Thanks.

Comment: youre passing the data the wrong way. Try replacing this: `{cat_id}` with this: `{cat_id:cat_id}`

Comment: @CodeGodie I edited but again those forms doesn't exist in $_POST.

Comment: when you say _"doesn't exist in $_POST."_ Do you mean, in your controller? Where are you trying to use $_POST, I dont see that in the code you provided.

Comment: @CodeGodie I just use `print_r($_POST);` But those inputs which retrieved from json, dose not exist. So , I can't insert them to database.

Comment: Again, I dont see where you are printing $_POST. Show it in your code so we can help you

Comment: @CodeGodie Never mind, Because it prints all other inputs which are in the html. This is created by json.

Comment: dude if you need more help, I can try to point you in the right direction through Teamviewer, let me know.

Comment: @CodeGodie my id is 909 943 824. Thanks.

Comment: @CodeGodie It is 8508.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok after inspecting your code, the problem was your FORM tags. They were being placed in the wrong places. Make sure if you open a form tag inside a div, you need to close it inside that same div, not outside or the DOM will break it.