# Codeigniter upload issue: file_name doesn't work fine

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I use codeigniter and in upload file I have problem. `file_name` is produced Repetitiously.

**My Model:** (db_category)

```
public function do_upload($route = "./category-pic/") {
    $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
            'upload_path'   => $route,
            'encrypt_name'  => 'TRUE',
            'max_size'      =>  3000
    );
    $this->load->library("upload", $config);
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
$this->db_category->do_upload("./product-pic/");
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
    $this->upload->do_upload($key);
    $data_name = $this->upload->data();
    $k++;
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file'.$k]['tmp_name'])) {
        // This is produced Repetitiously sometimes for different pictures.
        echo $data_name['file_name']. " ****** ";
    }
}
```

**My view** is simple and static like :

```
echo '<input type="file" name="file1" id="my_uploader" style="width: 210px;" />' ;
echo '<input type="file" name="file2" id="my_uploader" style="width: 210px;" />';
echo '<input type="file" name="file3" id="my_uploader" style="width: 210px;" />';
echo '<input type="file" name="file4" id="my_uploader" style="width: 210px;" />';
```

**NOTE:** All pictures uploads fine with their own names, but the problem is in `$data_name['file_name']`.

What is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer! It was a bad mistake from view part.

Input files was not written in order. For example it was like this:

```
echo '<input type="file" name="file5" id="my_uploader" style="width: 210px;" />' ;
echo '<input type="file" name="file2" id="my_uploader" style="width: 210px;" />';
echo '<input type="file" name="file3" id="my_uploader" style="width: 210px;" />';
```

I don't know why this can cause problem.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$data_name['file_name'];
```

use

```
$_FILES['file'.$k]['name'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But there is a problem. Codeigniter changes the picture name by `'encrypt_name'  =>  'TRUE'` but your php code does not, and I insert to database with original name.

Comment: can you please show me the $data_name variable. echo "<pre>".$print_r($data_name)."</pre>";

Comment: You see, after first one, 3 of them are the same! But they are uploaded fine.

Comment: can show me the function which update the database please.

Comment: some how you need to refresh the $data_name variable.

Comment: Please see edit 2 for query part. But it doesn't relates to that part.

Comment: I refresh $data_name after each upload by this code : `$data_name = array();` But it's the same problem.

Comment: Finally I found the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote it as an answer.

Comment: ok but the view was posted with your question was in order :)

Comment: Yes a part of that was in order, not all of them :D I lost a half day for a bad mistake.

Comment: Yes :) also see here, and accepted answer :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162432/created-input-form-by-json-doesnt-show-in-post